# Fluid layout with z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have an interface where user can drag an element (eg: video or image) to any desired location on the screen of an html page. Once the user has positioned an element, the z-index location is saved (x-positiom , y-position , width and height).

My client has this requirement where it should be a in a fluid layout manner where the position will change when it is viewed in a different screen resolution (iphone, ipad,tablet and others). Is this possible? Can someone advice me on this, please.

Comment: If you save the x,y positions you can then calculate what is the current box that you are above (in flex box model you can define several 'boxes' and use it to layout them dynamically).

Comment: It seems interesting. Could you help me elaborate and mind answering it so that i can vote you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you save the x,y positions you can then calculate what is the current box that you are above (in flex box model you can define several 'boxes' and use it to layout them dynamically). The idea is to take the draggable obj. and see what is the element that its being dropped at...

You can use this code to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/greenido/pFsCL/